# Find all image sizes (height and width) in wordpress pictures with a php wordpress function?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

What is the WordPress function to find all the file thumbnails sizes it creates?

Is there is a function to list a thumbnail size array wp_image_sizes($postid) - if there was such a thing.

I am using the most common thumb nail sizes it creates for my site on here, but then it creates more than these sizes that I can't erase right away - I have to do manually.

The code below is the way I delete them with the base picture name I store in the database.

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
require( './wp-load.php' ); // load wordpress functions which aren't used in this code, but are for the delete.php.

$extension = array_pop(explode( '.', $pic_name ) ); // .jpg
$pic_name =remove_ext($pic_name, "."); // bare name picture
$pic_sizes = array("-40x40", "-300x300", "-150x150", "-100x100", "-300x240");// word press picture sizes it creates
foreach($pic_sizes as $p){
    $deletefilename = $pic_name ."$p.".$extension;
    include "delete.php";//my code to delete the pictures based upon name
}
function remove_ext($string, $delimiter){
    $a = explode($delimiter, $string);
    array_pop($a);
    return implode($delimiter, $a);
}
```

Comment: a WordPress function to find all the file thumbnails sizes it creates - it says it right there.  Please don't down vote so quickly.  I edited it for your pleasure.

Comment: The WordPress function to find all WordPress image file thumbnail sizes for a post.  I don't know how to explain it any further or simpler than that...

Comment: For example if there is a function to list the thumbnail size wp_image_size($postid) - if there was such a  thing

Comment: The closest thing I can find so far is get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment' ) ) https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

Comment: the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); They also have 'medium','medium_large','large','full'   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/  but even these don't seem to answer the question fully